# How to PInvoke Windows Build C++ DLL's in Mono running on Ubuntu

Tags: c#, c++, ubuntu, mono, native

I have an application that was built in .NET that contains several Pinvokes but not to native windows DLL's but to native C++ DLL's built using Visual Studio. When I execute the application on Ubuntu using mono "AppName.exe" the ui spins up with no issues but I am getting an error when trying to make a call to the native library. I am still new to mono and porting to linux.

Do I need to compile these C++ libraries in linux before I can PInvoke them? If so how do I take the VS C++ Dll and compile it natively on linux?

Here is a small segment of the Pinvoke statement:

```
[DllImport("gpc.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern void _gpc_create_polygon([In, Out] ref _gpc_vertex origin, [In, Out] ref int sides, [In, Out] ref double radius, 
                                                  [In, Out] ref _gpc_polygon result);
```

Update: Are C++ DLL's compiled against the VS C++ runtime runable via mono on linux or do they need to be compiled on linux nativly?

Comment: The best choice would be rebuild the libraries to Linux. Windows libraries won't work on Linux. You need Wine to run Windows application on Linux. But I'm not sure, if this will help you with the linked libraries from Mono. I never tested this.

Comment: @Julo I am able to run windows compiled apps on linux using mono with no issue. Wine is another option but I would prefer to stick with the mono framework. I was thinking also it could be since it was compiled and linked with the VsC++ runtime. Maybe that is not callable from Linux?

Comment: As far as I know, C/C++ libraries compiled for Windows won't work without Wine on Linux. .NET Framework (C#) compiled programs will work on Mono, but, there can not be any Windows specific function *(PInvoke to Windows libraries, Named pipes, Tray icon, and other functions, that are not (yet) implemented in Mono)*. You can for sure PInvoke libraries in Mono, but until now i have seen only Linux libraries be PInvoked in Linux/Mono. There is a slight chance/possibility, that even Windows libraries can be used from Mono on Linux, using Wine. But I would not get my hopes to high in this matter.